# React native AsyncStorage update details in phone

Tags: react-native

I am using react native in developing an android application. I am trying to update a profile on my phone by using the AsyncStorage. After inputting everything and saving my profile, it doesnt change anything. The name is still the same. Help

```
xport default class ControlPanel extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      firstName: '',
      middleName: '',
      lastName: '',
      address: '',
      contactNumber: ''
    }
    this.editUser = this.editUser.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("id").then(val => {
      this.setState({
          "id": val
      })
    }).done()
  }

  editUser(){
    fetch('http://plakaco.000webhostapp.com/api/createClient', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        c_fname: this.state.firstName,
        c_mname: this.state.middleName,
        c_lname: this.state.lastName,
        c_address: this.state.address,
        c_type: 'mobile',
        c_contact: this.state.contactNumber
      })
    }).then(response => {
      response.json().then(data => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("id", data.data.client_id.toString())
        this.setState({
          "id": data.data.client_id.toString()
        })
      })
      alert('User saved successfully!')
      this.clearState()
    }).catch(err => {
      alert('Save failed')
      this.clearState()
    })
  }

  clearState(){
    this.setState({
      firstName: '',
      middleName: '',
      lastName: '',
      address: '',
      contactNumber: ''
    })
  }
```

Comment: Where did you call your editUser function?

Answer (score 0):

First of all for setting in AsyncStorage
You have wrote -->

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("id", data.data.client_id.toString())
```

instead of that write like this-->

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("id", JSON.stringify(data.data.client_id))
```

and for getting from AsyncStorage
write this line -->

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("id").then((value) => {
   console.log("Your data is Here::-",value);
  // instead of console.log you can set this value into the state like this.
    this.setState({
      yourStateName:value
    })
}).done();
```